# Change color of line with stylesheet

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I draw a line which I would like to set the color and line width. In order to make my app customizable I would like to have this properties in the style sheet. How would I do that? I tried to subclass `QColor` without much success, as the line is still black. Here is what I tried:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor


class Main(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)

        painter.setPen(LineColor())
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)

        painter.end()


class LineColor(QColor):
    ''' Exposes a class, so that its color can be set using the style sheet '''


qss = '''
LineColor {
    color: red;
}
'''


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(qss)

main = Main()
main.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting, IMHO is not possible. Since you have sublassed `QMainWindow`, why don't you override `setStyleSheet`, and parse the stylesheet, and set the color accordingly?

```
class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(...) :
        ...
        ...
        ...

        self.myLineColor = QColor( Qt::black )
        ...
        ...

    def setStyleSheet( sheet ) :

        # Your code to parse the stylesheet
        self.myLineColor.setRgb( ... ) # or setNamedColor or similar.

        QMainWindow::setStyleSheet( self, sheet )

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)

        painter.setPen(self.myLineColor)
        painter.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)

        painter.end()
```